# plugin not found error in node.js command prompt

Tags: cumulocity

I have configured cumulocity.json as below:

```
{
  "name": "Cumulocityexercises",
  "availability": "PRIVATE",
  "contextPath": "cumulocityexercises",
  "key": "cumulocityexercises-appkey",
  "resourcesUrl": "/",
  "type": "HOSTED",
  "tabsHorizontal": true,
  "imports": [
    "core/c8yBranding",
    "cumulocityexercises/myplugin",
    "cumulocityexercises/docsplugin"
  ]
}
```

but when I am trying to build the `plugin:my plugin`, I am getting an error like plugin not found. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely linked to your project structure. It should look similar to the screenshot below and then you would need to run the command from the root level (cumulocity-enhanced-ui in the screenshot).

You need to run the following command to build a single plugin

```
c8y build:plugin <<pluginFolderName>>
c8y build:plugin dashboardUtils
```

Same goes for the manifest declarations. They need to match the plugin folder names (case sensitive)

[image: UI project structure]

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly the command you are using to build the plugin? 
If it is something like this:

```sh
$ c8y build:plugin docsplugin
docsplugin plugin not found
```

then you may check that your plugin directory has the same name as specified in the JSON file, i.e. *cumulocity.json* manifest file in the main app directory. A second manifest file goes in the plugin directory.

Note that you must execute the build command from the main app directory which in your case is *cumulocityexercises*, otherwise you will get the same error message.